# Как исправить мерцание фона в юнити?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Делаю игру и юзаю для генерации уровня tilemaps, а для камеры cinemachine. Возникла проблема: когда стартую сцену часть экрана возле камеры начинает мерцать.

Записал видео, чтобы было понятнее:

https://ru.files.fm/f/pa9hnx38 смотрите на левую сторону экрана, там время от времени будет мерцать фон.

Comment: воспроизводится ли данный эффект на релизном билде? Или же только в редакторе?

Comment: только в редакторе

Answer (score 1):

варианты решения проблемы:
добавить в ярлык к юнити "-force-opengl tag"

или попробовать отключить G-Sync на мониторе если такой есть.

Или попробуй донастроить NVidia драйвер для работы с юнити следующим образом:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

---

---

Если нет, ищи решения по запросу "Unity Editor Flickering"

Comment: Спасибо огромное. Сегодня попробую всё сделать))))